# ag grid how to export data to excel with bg color opacity?

Tags: ag-grid

I want to export data to excel using ag grid with excel styles, but I found that ag grid excel styles can only set color in six digit hex code like "#RRGGBB", other types like "#RGB" or "rgb(r, g, b)" or "#RRGGBBAA" or "rgba(r, g, b, a)" are not supported. Is there any solution to attach an opacity to excel styles ?

I tried to use all types of rgba color, none of them works except "#RRGGBB", I read the ag grid document, but they seems not mention it.